# Deploy on Azure + Flask + Python3 + GIT LFS generates 'error: external filter 'git-lfs smudge %f' failed -1'

Tags: python-3.x, flask, azure-devops, continuous-deployment, git-lfs

## the use case

- I have built a web app using Python3 and Flask.
- The app works locally
- the app is stored on https://bitbucket.org

### deployment on Azure

- I create a new 'app service'
- I set the parameters: Linux machine, Python 3.8, deployed in West Europe, Azure Plan B1
- I go to 'deployment center'

  - select bitbucket
  - select the repository
  - I hit 'deploy'

## The error

The deployment starts by cloning the source code but the process generates an error immediately

**git-lfs** seems to be the issue!

```
git-lfs smudge '.vscode/launch.json': 1: git-lfs smudge '.vscode/launch.json': git-lfs: Permission denied

error: external filter 'git-lfs smudge %f' failed -1

error: external filter 'git-lfs smudge %f' failed

fatal: .vscode/launch.json: smudge filter lfs failed

/usr/bin/git checkout master --force
```

**What should I do to overcome the issue?**

Many thanks for the time you will invest on this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a try using Azure devops pipeline to deploy to Azure app service.

You can click [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/get-started/pipelines-sign-up?view=azure-devops) to create an Azure DevOps organization if you donot have one.

Then follow below steps to create an azure devops pipeline

1,Sign in to your Azure DevOps organization and navigate to your project.

2, [Connect your azure subscription with Azure devops](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/connect-to-azure?view=azure-devops) pipeline with service connections

3,In your project, navigate to the Pipelines page. Then choose the action to create a new pipeline.

4, Choose Bitbucket Cloud(YAML) to create a pipeline in YAML pipeline, or select `use classic editor to create a UI pipeline

[image]

5, After you finishing creating your pipeline, `Edit` your pipeline to check the option `Checkout files from LFS`

In yaml pipeline, yon can find option `Checkout files from LFS` by following below steps.

Click **3dots**--> **Triggers**--> **YAML** tab-->**Get sources**

[image]

[image]

6, Configure your pipeline to build and deploy your python project. see example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/python-webapp?view=azure-devops).

Comment: this is what I did and it worked. it is not possible to push the code directly to Azure without going through the pipelines. 

FYI, I had to enable the GIT LFS too!